# System.Linq.Queryable.dll cannot be Decompiled

Tags: .net, linq, disassembly, dotpeek

I tried use DotPeek to decompile the System.Linq.Queryable.dll, but it only shows the metadata like below, this assembly resides in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Linq.Queryable.dll. But I decompiled another C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Web.dll assembly, it works fine.

I wonder why it happens like this ?

[image]

Comment: By design, there just isn't anything to look at.  It is merely a glue assembly with [TypeForwardedTo] attributes, meant to hide implementation differences with .NETCore and .NETStandard.  For .NET Framework 4.8 is forwards, say, System.Linq.Queryable to System.Core.dll.  Not sure if dotpeek can show this, I quickly got rid of it.  Unimpressed.

Comment: Where is Queryable class code put, is it in System.Linq.Queryable.dll ?

Comment: I know what you mean, I found that class's code in System.Core.dll under .Net framework 4.8

Comment: But where can I see [TypeForwardedTo] attribute in System.Linq.Queryable.dll, this attribute give me the clue for what happened.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/master/src/libraries/System.Linq.Queryable) you can find the source code of the above mentioned library.